# Prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,0)} \frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y} = x_0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove that

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,0)} \frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y} = x_0$$

I have tried the following, but I'm not sure if it is rigorous, especially in one step:

We have by L'Hôpital that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-h}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} e^{-h}=1$$ Then, because $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,0)} xy = 0$$ we have that

\begin{equation} 1 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-h}}{h} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,0)} \frac{1 - e^{-xy}}{xy} \tag{1}\end{equation}

So

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,0)} \frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,0)} x\frac{1-e^{-xy}}{xy} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,0)} x  \cdot \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,0)} \frac{1-e^{-xy}}{xy}= x_0 \cdot 1 = x_0$$

The step where I used a reasoning that I think it may not always be true is $(1)$

Comment: Your way is fine, we don't need l'Hospital indeed

$$\frac{1 - e^{-h}}{h}= \frac1{e^h}\frac{e^h - 1}{h} \to 1\cdot 1 =1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $x_0=0$ is clear.

Define $h:=xy$ and let $x\to x_0\neq 0$. Then $(x,y)\to (x_0,0)$ if and only if $h\to 0$. So (1) is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof by using the definition of limit.

We know that

$e^z=1+z+O\left(z^2\right)\;\;$ for any $\;z\in\Bbb R\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

and there exist $\;\alpha>0\,,\,C>0\,$ such that

$\left|O\left(z^2\right)\right|\leqslant Cz^2\;\;$ for any $\,z\in\left]\,-\alpha,\alpha\,\right[\;.\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

Consequently, from $\,(*)\,,\,$ it results that

$e^{-xy}=1-xy+O\left(x^2y^2\right)\;\;$ for any $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\,.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$

Let $\;x_0\in\Bbb R\;$ and let $\;\beta=\min\left\{1,\dfrac{\alpha}{1+|x_0|}\right\}>0\;.$

For any $\;x\in\left]\,x_0\!-\!\beta,x_0\!+\!\beta\,\right[\;$ and for any $\;y\in\left]\,-\beta,\beta\,\right[\;$

$|xy|=|(x-x_0)y+x_0y|\leqslant|x-x_0||y|+|x_0||y|\color{red}{\mathbf{\,<\,}}$
$\color{red}{\mathbf{\,<\,}}\beta^2+|x_0|\beta\leqslant\beta+|x_0|\beta=\beta\left(1+|x_0|\right)\leqslant\alpha$

and, from $\,(**)\,$ for $\,z\!=\!xy\,,\,$ we get that $\;\left|O\!\left(x^2y^2\right)\right|\leqslant Cx^2y^2.$

So we have proved that

$\left|O\!\left(x^2y^2\right)\right|\leqslant Cx^2y^2\;,\;\forall x\!\in\!\left]x_0\!-\!\beta,x_0\!+\!\beta\right[,\,\forall y\!\in\!\left]-\beta,\beta\right[.\;\color{blue}{(2)}$

Moreover ,

for any $\,\varepsilon>0\,$ there exists $\,\delta_{\varepsilon}\!=\min\!\left\{\!\beta,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{1\!+\!C(1\!+\!|x_0|)^2}\!\right\}\!>0$

such that for any $\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\land\,y\!\neq\!0\,\land\,\sqrt{(x\!-\!x_0)^2\!+\!y^2}<\delta_{\varepsilon}$

it results that

$\left|\dfrac{1\!-\!e^{-xy}}y\!-\!x_0\right|\underset{(1)}{=}\left|\dfrac{xy\!-\!O\!\left(x^2y^2\right)}y\!-\!x_0\right|\!=\!\left|x\!-\!x_0\!-\!\dfrac{O\!\left(x^2y^2\right)}y\right|\!\leqslant$

$\leqslant|x-x_0|+\dfrac{\left|O\!\left(x^2y^2\right)\right|}{|y|}\underset{(2)}{\color{red}{\mathbf{\,<\,}}}\delta_{\varepsilon}+\dfrac{Cx^2y^2}{|y|}=\delta_{\varepsilon}+Cx^2|y|\leqslant$

$\leqslant\delta_{\varepsilon}+Cx^2\delta_{\varepsilon}=\delta_{\varepsilon}\left[1+C(x-x_0+x_0)^2\right]=$

$=\delta_{\varepsilon}\left[1+C(x-x_0)^2+2C(x-x_0)x_0+Cx_0^2\right]\leqslant$

$\leqslant\delta_{\varepsilon}\left[1+C(x-x_0)^2+2C|x_0||x-x_0|+Cx_0^2\right]\color{red}{\mathbf{<\,}}$

$\color{red}{\mathbf{<\,}}\delta_{\varepsilon}\left[1+C\delta_{\varepsilon}^2+2C|x_0|\delta_{\varepsilon}+Cx_0^2\right]\underset{\overbrace{\text{ because }\,\delta_{\varepsilon}\leqslant\beta\leqslant1\;}}{\leqslant}$

$\leqslant\delta_{\varepsilon}\left[1+C+2C|x_0|+Cx_0^2\right]=\delta_{\varepsilon}\left[1\!+\!C(1\!+\!|x_0|)^2\right]\leqslant\varepsilon\;.$

Consequently, by definition of limit, it follows that

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(x_0,0)}\dfrac{1-e^{-xy}}y=x_0\;.$